# Adobe Analytics - Force a session/userID refresh

Tags: session, adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

We have a website  that can be viwed from a kiosk in a shop.

When the inactivity is above 2 minutes, the site returns to the home.

Anyone knows how to refresh the session when this appens?
It could also serve make a refresh of the user id, but I don't know how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are talking about Adobe Analytics javascript library and not the Android/iOS SDK, based on your tagging and lack of mention of it. If your kiosk **is** in fact using Android or iOS SDK, then please comment and I can update with instructions for that.

Adobe Analytics javascript library does not currently offer a direct method to force refresh an Adobe Analytics session/userID. However, you can effectively do it by explicitly setting [`s.visitorID`](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/visitorID.html) yourself, which will override the default generated by the library.

So, when you want to start a new session, you can pop `s.visitorID` with for example the current timestamp:

`s.visitorID = (new Date()).getTime().toString();`

Or maybe you already have a "session" id you generate that you can use, instead.

**Note:** with this method, you must set `s.visitorID` (with the same value) for *every hit* for the duration of your session. So in practice, you would really do something more along the lines of generate the new value at start of session, put the value in a cookie, and put `s.visitorID` in `s_doPlugin` but it reads the cookie value.

**Note:** This will effectively make your visits and visitors metrics the same. Which is to be expected with a publicly shared device, but just mentioning it in case it comes up later.

**pseudocode:**

```
function startNewSession() {

  // use whatever cookie writing utility you have to 
  // set a cookie named visitorID set to the generated 
  // value. In practice, the expiration doesn't really 
  // matter as long as it's something longer than 
  // your average session. Just setting it to default 
  // session expiration should be okay
  var visitorID = (new Date()).getTime().toString();
  setCookie('visitorID',visitorID);

}

// in your existing logic that times out returning 
// home after 2 minutes of inactivity, call the function
// to generate a new id
startNewSession(); 

// this is AA's s_doPlugins callback function. This may look
// slightly different, maybe defined as s_doPlugins and then assigned
// to s.doPlugins, depending on what AA lib version you are using.
// This is AA's callback function that gets called whenever 
// an s.t or s.tl call is made
s.usePlugins=true;
s.doPlugins=function(s) {

  // make sure visitorID variable is addedto linkTrackVars
  // so it gets 'registered' for s.tl calls.
  s.linkTrackVars='visitorID';

  // explicitly set the visitorID with the cookie, using 
  // whatever cookie reading utility you have.
  s.visitorID=readCookie('visitorID');   

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! Sorry, I should have given more information about my issue. I tried your recomendation but the Analytics Visitor ID (debuggin with ObservePoint) remains the same value. It can be because we use Marketing Cloud ID?? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It may be a bug with what ObservePoint is reporting to you. Check the raw URL request. If you explicitly set `s.visitorID` it takes precedence over all of the other visitor id values even if they are in the request

Comment: I try it but the visitorID remains the same... I think that Omniture use the AMCV cookie to identify the user.

Comment: @JaviVillar Yes, you will still see that cookie. But if you explicitly set `s.visitorID`, Adobe will use that instead (when attributing data during processing), because it is the highest precedence for [order of operations for analytics ids](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/mcvid/mcvid-analytics-order-of-operations.html). You won't actually see the id you set in `s.visitorID` used in AA's cookies.

Comment: So to be clear, you may still see other cookies being set or other IDs being sent in the request url, too. And you may even see tools like ObservePoint  or similar get confused and report the wrong one as the visitor ID adobe uses. But the link I provided shows the order of operations Adobe uses on their server during processing. Just make sure you see `vid=` param in the http request to Adobe and you should be okay.

Comment: Thank you so much! You're right, now I send the vID to Omniture with other id variable(mid, aid...). Now, I think that we are changing the user ID correctly but I need to wait to check it, this is AA...